# Replacing a $G$-CW-complex with a $G$-homotopy equivalent $G$-simplicial complex - can anyone supply a reference?

Tags: cw-complexes, equivariant-homotopy

Let $G$ be a group (not a topological group, just a group). By a $G$-complex I mean a CW-complex with an action of $G$ that takes cells to cells so that the pointwise and setwise stabilizer of each cell coincide. Does anyone know a good reference for the fact that every $G$-complex is $G$-homotopy equivalent to a $G$-simplicial complex of the same dimension?

Comment: Can we make any assumptions at all about $G$? Most of the literature proves results when $G$ is finite.

Comment: I am interested in the general case although a reference that covers the case when $G$ is finite could starting point.

Comment: Google supplies this https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1980-258-02/S0002-9947-1980-0558178-7/S0002-9947-1980-0558178-7.pdf Lemma 4.3 which seems related

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg It seems that Stefan Waner is assuming $G$ is a compact Lie group in the paper you put forward which gives me some reservations about this being the right reference. This does certainly address the case $G$ is finite!

Comment: A reference for the equivariant Whitehead theorem outside the compact Lie case is in Matumoto's "On G-CW complexes and a theorem of JHC Whitehead" (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/matumoto.pdf). This at least reduces the question to one about constructing a weakly equivalent simplicial complex which seems roughly the same as section 5 of Waner's paper. The "equal dimension" part may be a little trickier. Unfortunately this doesn't really count as a reference.

Comment: @TylerLawson, Waner’s paper doesn’t assume compactness footprint the equivariant whitehead theorem but unfortunately does in section 4, which I missed when I gave the reference.